# React-Redux only lastet changed state is shown correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need some states from different component
But atm only the latest state that changed is shown when i console.log them is shown correctly 3 out the 4 are undefined.

My Action and Reduxer

```
export const paypal_error =
  (time, timevalidation, acceptBox, sliderDeliveryValue) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'PAYPAL_ERROR',
      payload: {
        time,
        timevalidation,
        acceptBox,
        sliderDeliveryValue,
      },
    });
  };


export const paypalReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PAYPAL_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        time: action.payload.time,
        timevalidation: action.payload.timevalidation,
        acceptBox: action.payload.acceptBox,
        sliderDeliveryValue: action.payload.sliderDeliveryValue,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My dispatchs, each in a different component

```
dispatch(paypal_error({ time: date }))
dispatch(paypal_error({ sliderDeliveryValue: event.target.value }));
dispatch(paypal_error({ timeValidation: false }));
dispatch(paypal_error({ acceptBox: !acceptBox }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending *partial* state updates but assuming *full* updates in the reducer function. You'll need some logic to handle partial updates so you aren't overwriting existing state that is undefined in the action payload. You can simply provide a fallback value of the current existing state value properties for each that you might be updating.

Example:

```
export const paypalReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PAYPAL_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        time: action.payload.time ?? state.time,
        timevalidation: action.payload.timevalidation ?? state.timevalidation,
        acceptBox: action.payload.acceptBox ?? state.acceptbox,
        sliderDeliveryValue:
          action.payload.sliderDeliveryValue ?? state.sliderDeliveryValue,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Additionally, the `paypal_error` action creator takes up to 4 arguments:

```
paypal_error = (time, timevalidation, acceptBox, sliderDeliveryValue) => ...
```

Either pass the four args:

```
dispatch(paypal_error(date));
dispatch(paypal_error(undefined, undefined, undefined, event.target.value));
dispatch(paypal_error(undefined, false));
dispatch(paypal_error(undefined, undefined, !acceptBox));
```

Or update the action creator to take a single object argument:

```
paypal_error = ({
  time,
  timevalidation,
  acceptBox,
  sliderDeliveryValue
}) => ...
```

Since the `paypal_error` action creator also doesn't appear to be an asynchronous action it doesn't need to return a function with a call to `dispatch`, it can simply return the action object with computed `payload` property.

```
export const paypal_error = ({
  acceptBox,
  sliderDeliveryValue
  time,
  timevalidation,
}) => ({
  type: 'PAYPAL_ERROR',
  payload: {
    acceptBox,
    sliderDeliveryValue
    time,
    timevalidation,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to spread the `state` variable

```
return {
    ...state,
    time: action.payload.time,
    timevalidation: action.payload.timevalidation,
    acceptBox: action.payload.acceptBox,
    sliderDeliveryValue: action.payload.sliderDeliveryValue,
};
```

Edit 1:
As [gunwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522330/gunwin) said, initial state have to be `{}`

Edit 2:

Your `paypal_error` function should not take `dispatch` as an argument if you don't use it

```
export const paypal_error =
  (time, timevalidation, acceptBox, sliderDeliveryValue) => ({
    type: 'PAYPAL_ERROR',
    payload: {
      time,
      timevalidation,
      acceptBox,
      sliderDeliveryValue
    }
  });
```

Comment: Also, the default value for `state` shouldn't be false, at the least it should be `{}`.

Comment: I changed both, the default Value and the spread state but the issue remains